# How do you get the current sessid from web address and use it in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a noob question, network admin unknowingly turned into web developer :) I am trying to understand how to get the current sessid and put it into the javascript where sessid= (current sessid), its on the web address and is generated when you visit the search page. ex: http://www.southerntiredirect.com/shop/catalog/search?sessid=uUQgRHQyekRGJcyWwTFwf5hxep7cdYlV4CdKfunmjxNOQPEgDZdJD2tNgRsD7Prm&shop_param=

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var url= "http://www.southerntiredirect.com/online/system/ajax_search_manufacturer?sessid=????????";
  </script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.southerntiredirect.com/online/templatemedia/all_lang/manufacturer.js"></script><input type="hidden" name="sessid" value="sessid??????">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regexp:

```
var url = "http://www.southerntiredirect.com/shop/catalog/search?sessid=uUQgRHQyekRGJcyWwTFwf5hxep7cdYlV4CdKfunmjxNOQPEgDZdJD2tNgRsD7Prm&shop_param=";
var match = url.match(/sessid=([^&]+)/);
if (match === null) {
    throw new Error("now what? D:");
}
var sessid = match[1];
```

The regexp in English: look for `"sessid="` then capture anything that isn't an `&`

Comment: I'd probably add a check for a match before trying to grab the first group.

Comment: You could do that. If the match fails `match` will be `null`, so you can check for that.

Comment: What should I put in the "sessid="

var url= "http://www.southerntiredirect.com/online/system/ajax_search_manufacturer?sessid="

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: How does the Var url= statment get the current sessid, when I inspect element on the site it has the current sessid from the url inside the var url already.

Answer (score 0):

Use my handy-dandy library URLTools!

**Library**

```
//URLTools- a tiny js library for accessing parts of the url
function urlAnalyze(url) {
    if (url == undefined) {var url = document.location.toString();}
    url = url.replace(/\%20/g," ");
    //seperates the parts of the url
    var parts = url.split("?");
    //splits into sperate key=values
    if (parts[1] == undefined) {return 1;}
    var keyValues = parts[1].split("&");
    var key = function () {}
    keyValues.forEach(function (keyValue) {
        var keyAndValue = keyValue.split("=");
        key[keyAndValue[0]] = keyAndValue[1];
    });
    return key;
}
```

Then, just call URLAnalyze and get the sessid key.

**Usage**

```
var urlKeys = urlAnalyze(),
    sessid = urlKeys["sessid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/) is a great function that grabs whatever you want and returns the key, value for it.

The main portion of this function gets the url using `window.location.href` and then performs a regular expression on it to find botht he key and the value.

I DO NOT TAKE CREDIT FOR THIS CODE.

*Please go the [link](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/) to see the full example*

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
        function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
    return vars;
}
```